# Stream video from secure azure blob to WPF

Tags: wpf, azure, azure-blob-storage

Does anyone know a way to stream .mp4 video from a secure azure blob (via https) into a WPF application.

I'm generating the uri as follows ...

```
public Uri GetSecureUriForBlob(CloudBlobContainer container, string blobName)
{
    var blockBlob = container.GetBlockBlobReference(blobName);
    var beforeOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddMinutes(-5));
    var afterOffset = new DateTimeOffset(DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(1));

    var builder = new UriBuilder(blockBlob.Uri)
    {
        Query = blockBlob.GetSharedAccessSignature(
            new SharedAccessBlobPolicy
            {
                Permissions = SharedAccessBlobPermissions.Read,
                SharedAccessStartTime = beforeOffset,
                SharedAccessExpiryTime = afterOffset
            }).TrimStart('?')
    };

    return builder.Uri;
}
```

I've checked that the service version is set to at least "2013-08-15" and that the blob item has the correct content type set.

I know the format of the uri is correct, because I can paste it in a browser, and also use it in a Windows 8 store application, and the video streams correctly.

However, when I assign the same uri as the source for a WPF MediaElement, I get a NullReferenceException deep in the inner workings of MediaPlayer.Open().

Comment: could you provide a non expiring url to a sample video?

Comment: The test videos are the standard reference files such as http://download.blender.org/peach/bigbuckbunny_movies/BigBuckBunny_320x180.mp4, but fixed so that the header is at the start of the file rather than the end using http://renaun.com/blog/2010/06/qtindexswapper-2/. As I said they stream fine in a web browser and windows 8.1 store application, just not in WPF. They will also stream fine from a non-secure blob container to WPF, but the nature of the content (possible police evidence) requires a secure container to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There seems to be a [known issue with WPF MediaElement when playing from HTTPS](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/934355/in-a-wpf-standalone-application-exe-when-the-source-of-a-mediaelement-is-set-to-a-https-uri-it-throws-a-nullreferenceexception) endpoints. There are no issues when playing over plain HTTP (without "S").

This is not Microsoft Azure related, or Blob Related. This is pure WPF issue, that however seems that will not be fixed soon, if fixed at all.

For HTTPS Streams you can use either Silverlight or Windows 8 Modern applications - both support HTTPS streams without any issues.

You could probably find a 3rd party control for WPF that supports playing media over HTTPS.

**UPDATE**

Using the [VideoLan.NET WPF Controls](http://vlcdotnet.codeplex.com/) I was able to make HTTPS media playing. So far the only controls for WPF that successfully play HTTPS media. This requires a valid installation of VideoLAN VLC player for Windows. I used [the portable one (ZIP package)](http://www.videolan.org/vlc/download-windows.html) and it works perfectly. Documentation for the VideoLan.NET is a bit messy, but the result is that you can safely play HTTPS streams/progressive downloads in WPF.